# Populating a pop out table using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I am creating a table where one of the column values is a button, and this button opens a pop out dialog box, this box needs to hold a table, where the values in the table are dependent on which row in the column you have clicked on. Im assuming ajax will be the easiest way to do this but im new to it so im not sure. any suggestions?

Comment: This is called a "modal dialog". Look it up: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+modal+dialog

Comment: yes the dialog box is displaying fine thats not the issue, the issue is I dont know how to populate the table for each row

Comment: You don't need AJAX unless you need/put something from the server - how. How this works depends on YOUR CODE, which you have not included in your question.

Comment: i do need to pull data from a server. so regardless of my code is there a way to populate a table using ajax, based on a click event